# proc_open not working when pass command as variable

Tags: php, ubuntu, rrdtool, proc-open

I am trying to execute command using php . when I pass command into proc_open function directly it can be executed fine like this

```
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w")
    );
    $cwd = '/temp/';
    $env = null;
    $blocking = false;




   echo $process = proc_open("rrdtool graph 4Rw6S0spak2zoPw9.png DEF:LOAD=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:AVERAGE DEF:LOAD_max=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:MAX DEF:LOAD_min=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:MIN AREA:LOAD#9999cc: AREA:LOAD_max#9999cc: COMMENT:'% CPU Now Ave Max\n' LINE1.25:LOAD#0000cc:' ' GPRINT:LOAD:LAST:%6.2lf%s GPRINT:LOAD:AVERAGE:%6.2lf%s GPRINT:LOAD_max:MAX:%6.2lf%s\\n COMMENT:\n HRULE:0#555555 --title='CPU' ", $descriptorspec, $pipe, $cwd,$env);
```

the above code is working fine and command executed without any error , but when I passing command through variable it didn't executed . this is the code when I passing command as variable

```
$cmd="rrdtool graph 4Rw6S0spak2zoPw9.png DEF:LOAD=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:AVERAGE DEF:LOAD_max=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:MAX DEF:LOAD_min=/var/www/html/rrd/10.10.0.144/fortigate_cpu.rrd:LOAD:MIN AREA:LOAD#9999cc: AREA:LOAD_max#9999cc: COMMENT:'% CPU Now Ave Max\n' LINE1.25:LOAD#0000cc:' ' GPRINT:LOAD:LAST:%6.2lf%s GPRINT:LOAD:AVERAGE:%6.2lf%s GPRINT:LOAD_max:MAX:%6.2lf%s\\n COMMENT:\n HRULE:0#555555 --title='CPU' "
   $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w")
    );
    $cwd = '/temp/';
    $env = null;
    $blocking = false;




   echo $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipe, $cwd,$env);
```

this code returned only the number of process but there is no file created

Comment: Do you have correct escaping of all the \ in the command line?  It may be that the command is not running due to syntax error.

Comment: I escaped all things but can not be run the command

Comment: If this is passing the command to a shell as-is, you might also need to quote all other parameters, especially ones containing "#" as this is a comment character